# How to log latency from remote sites to web server?

Tags: web-server, http, latency

I have a web server that works great for North American users, but users from Asia will have problems every once in a while. I need to collect some data and the first set is to get some trending for the latency in that area.

If I have access to a machine in the remote area, what software should I set up to log and graph the latency to the web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

smokeping is one further tool you'll want to look at

More generally you're better off using a monitoring service instead of going through the hassle of getting a local VM where you're trying to do the monitoring from. This should allow you to get views from various places around the world without the hassle of setting up your own VMs. Companies like Pingdom offer a free service for a single check. I'm sure there a plenty of other distributed monitoring service that could do the job.

Comment: Given the disparate geographical nature of what you need, you'll want to go with a commercial monitoring service that already has dispersed servers.  Trying to do it yourself will be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

you can run munin or cacti on remote locations to graph the latency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `httperf` and/or `ab` for benchmarking and collecting performance statistics. [This page](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/WebServerBenchmarking.html) shows some samples.